# Sort regex matches by alphabet

Tags: javascript, regex, sorting, pattern-matching, alphabetical

This is my HTML

```
<div id="all">3xOrange;2xBlue;1xRed;1xRed;1xRed;1xOrange;2xBlue;3xRed;1xBlue;1xRed;2xBlue;3xRed;1xBlue;1xRed;2xBlue;3xRed;1xBlue;1xRed;2xBlue;3xRed;1xBlue;1xRed;2xOrange;3xRed;1xBlue;1xRed;2xBlue;3xRed;1xBlue;1xRed;20xBlue;33xRed;20xBlue;33xRed;2xBlue;3xRed;51xBlue;51xRed;</div>
```

My goal is to display regex matches and sort the results by alphabet, but my regex matches start with number and x, the sorting should ignore `/\d+x` and sort by next leter so the result will be like this:*(2xBlue;2xBlue;3xOrange;1xOrange;1xRed;1xRed;1xRed;3xRed;......)*

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var words = document.body.textContent || document.body.innerText,
    matches = words.match(/\d+x[^;]*;/g);

   function strDes(a, b) {
       if (a>b) return -1;
       else if (a<b) return 1;
       else return 0;
     }
     var a2=matches;
     a2.sort(strDes);
$('#myDiv').text(a2).html(a2);
```

This is what I got so far , it dispalays matches and sort them but just by the number at front witch I want to ignore, please help

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick and works fine for now :)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var words = document.body.textContent || document.body.innerText,
    matches = words.match(/\d+x[^;]*;/g);
    function strDes(a, b) {
        a = a.split('x')[1];
        b = b.split('x')[1];
       if (a<b) return -1;
       else if (a>b) return 1;
       else return 0;
     }
     var a2=matches;
     a2.sort(strDes);


    $('#myDiv').text(a2).html(a2);
```